# Applying LayoutParams hides the View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tablelayout, android-layoutparams

In the code snippet below there's one commented line. When I uncomment that line, then the contents of `LinearLayout` are not displayed in a `TableRow`. Without setting the `LayoutParams`, the row displays both texts. I don't understand this behavior. I know that I can include complex views via `xml` files, but I'd rather understand what's wrong with this code:

```
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this );
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    // when I comment out this line, the row only shows the second text.
    // linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    TextView textLabel = new TextView(this);
    textLabel.setText("inside linear layout");
    linearLayout.addView(textLabel);

    TextView message = new TextView(this);
    message.setText( "inside tablerow");

    tableRow.addView(linearLayout);
    tableRow.addView(message);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

Comment: maybe you forget to add layout params for text view? i think width and height of TextView now is 0dp, and linearLayout has match_parent params, so because of this u see empty view

Comment: When I use `textLabel.setHeight(20); textLabel.setWidth(20)` it also doesn't show

Comment: try to change layoutParams source of linearLayout
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

Comment: Thank for the tip. I tried now to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` but it still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the question is something like *"What's the issue of this? How to resolve this?"*, here's my answer:

When you are setting `LayoutParams` to a `View`, those params would be used by the parent of this `View` to layout that `View` appropriately. So in your case what you have done is following:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(...);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tableRow.addView(linearLayout);
```

Now, the `tableRow` is confused, because it expects `TableRow.LayoutParams` in order to layout the view appropriately, but it suddenly finds out some other layout params. Whereas, had you **not** explicitly specified params (i.e. when  `linearLayout.setLayoutParams()` is commented out), the default layout params [would be generated](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TableRow.java#363).

```
    @Override
    protected LinearLayout.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(); // this is TableRow.LayoutParams
    }
```

So, instead of creating `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, create `TableRow.LayoutParams`:

```
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(...);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tableRow.addView(linearLayout);
```